# calling method for my thread object i created but is not working. no errors

Tags: java, multithreading, methods, constructor, boolean

Here's the code...

```
import java.util.Scanner;

class Draft extends Thread
{

    String name;
    static int counter;
    boolean islive; //...

//  the constructor
    public Draft(String name, int counter, boolean islive)
    {
        this.name = name;
        this.counter = counter;
        this.islive = islive;   //...
    }

    void stopTheThread()
    {
        this.islive = false;    //...
    }

    @Override
    public void run()
    {
        while(islive)   //...
        {
            counter++;
            try
            {
                sleep(913);
            }
            catch (InterruptedException e) { } 
        }
    }

//  the main function
    public static void main(String[] args)
    {
//      intializing two threads
        Draft Tone = new Draft("Tone", 13, true);
        Draft Ttwo = new Draft("Ttwo", 26, true);

        System.out.println("All Thread Started!");
        Tone.start();    Ttwo.start();

        Scanner scan = new Scanner(System.in);
        String go = "";

//      the while loop.......
        while(!go.toLowerCase().equals("exit")) {

            System.out.println();   //just a new line
            System.out.print("Command: ");
            go = scan.next();

            if(go.equals("1")) {
                System.out.print("Thread one "+ Tone.counter);
            }
            else if(go.equals("2")) {
                System.out.print("Thread wo: "+ Ttwo.counter);
            } 
            else if(go.equals("1Stop")) {
                Tone.stopTheThread();   //is not stoping
                System.out.print("Thread one Stopped"); //but printing
            } 
            else if(go.equals("2Stop")) {
                Ttwo.stopTheThread();   //is not stopping too
                System.out.print("Thread two Stopped"); //printing too
            }

        }//end of the while

    }//end of main

}   //end of Draft
```

I extended Thread Class for my Draft class.
on the **run** method the thread mainly runs on the while loop under the condition **isalive** which is a boolean.

i created a method ***stopTheThread*** which sets the **isalive** to false and the loop on **run** method should stop. 
but actually it isnt stopping when i'm calling it in my main method for **Tone** & **Ttwo**. both are two thread object created on the main method.

All the conditions are checked.

*Whats wrong I did there?*

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Looks like both threads are incrementing same STATIC counter variable, so both of them are running and increasing the same variable.
I tested the code and works as expected, counter is incremented until I "stop" BOTH treads, if you want each thread to increment its own variable, you should remove the static modifier.

Comment: but I created two deferent object. Tone and Ttwo. and counter should be deferrent for each object. then why both thread would increament the same counter. i didnt get it. will u pls explain a little more?

Comment: and why you mentioned static here? if I remove the static it works. why?

Comment: @Rabin: what do you think, does `static` mean?

Comment: @Rabin Static means there will be one one shared unique instance no matter how many instances of the containing class (Draft) are created, every single one will share that same static object (counter).

Comment: @DanielRodriguez so my two thread instance was using the same counter. thats why while i stopped one thread, counter was still increamenting by the another thread until i stop that too.

Is that the only thing static does? why we use static in main method usualy? will u plz explain?

Comment: @Rabin static means a variable (or method) is a member of the Class, not the Object (an instance of the class), so, in your example, Draft (class) has a member (static) named counter, and that single instance is accessed by two objects (instances of Draft). The method main "public static final void main(String args[])" in any class means that class can be run (as a starting point) by java.